# Pennsylvania is not a state, it is a Commonwealth. Why?

Tags: united-states

Why is Pennsylvania a Commonwealth and not a state?

Comment: It **is** a state that just happened to call itself a Commonwealth. Like Virginia, Kentucky, Massachusetts. When these states chose it, the name "Commonwealth" signified it was a government of the people.

Answer (score 9):

The founders of the Pennsylvania colony (and Massachusetts, Virginia and Kentucky for that matter) were inspired by the writings of English philosophers like [John Locke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Locke) and [Thomas Hobbes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hobbes); and so emphasised that their colony's authority derived from the people by formally calling themselves a Commonwealth.

This wasn't necessarily different from other states that chose call themselves Republics (like *Vermont Republic*) or Provinces (like *Province of New Hampshire*) or Colonies (like *Delaware Colony*) prior to the creation of the United States.

Comment: The term '[Commonwealth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth)' is quite popular in the Anglosphere; and less dubious than '[People's Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Republic)' has become, even if they both started as generic ways to say much the same thing.